# Xamarin forms, PDF shows up on iOS Simulator but not on the real iPad

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have a custom webview renderer to display a PDF that i have downloaded from an API call. I save the PDF to local storage and display it via custom webview renderer. It works perfectly fine on the simulator, but when i tried on real iPad, the page just shows blank (except for the page title at the top).
This is the custom render code to display.

```
using MyProject.Core.Controls;
using MyProject.Core.Helpers;
using MyProject.Core.Services.FileStorage;
using MyProject.iOS.Renderers;
using Foundation;
using WebKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PDFWebViewer), typeof(PDFWebViewerRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class PDFWebViewerRenderer : ViewRenderer<PDFWebViewer, WKWebView>
    {
        PDFWebViewer WebViewer => Element as PDFWebViewer;

        WKUserContentController userController;

        protected async override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<PDFWebViewer> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                userController = new WKUserContentController();

                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
                var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
                userController.Dispose();
                var webViewer = e.OldElement as PDFWebViewer;
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                //var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;

                var filepath = await FileStorageService.FileExists(Constant.Agreement.AGREEMENT_PDF_PREVIEW);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
                {
                    var request = new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl($"file://" + filepath));
                    Control.LoadRequest(request);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the debugger, i checkedand this is the file path `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A9D74D50-7466-4F9E-8986-77F8305BD179/Documents/../Library/AGREEMENT_PREVIEW.pdf`

and this is the request that it is passing to the `Control.LoadRequest()`,
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A9D74D50-7466-4F9E-8986-77F8305BD179/Documents/../Library/AGREEMENT_PREVIEW.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. For some reason real devices don't like                     `Control.LoadRequest(request);`

what worked for me was

```
var request = new NSUrl($"file://" + filepath);
Control.LoadFileUrl(request, request);
```

hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Thank you so much! you saved my time! :)